# Yarn PnP fallback mode and scripts

Tags: yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2

I am using `pnpFallbackMode: all` and specify some common dev dependencies in the package root, then I am using yarn workspaces for my components.

I am able to resolve package dependencies defined in the root this way, but I am unable to run tools.

For example, when defining TypeScript as a dev dependency in the root package.json, I get

```
$ yarn tsc
Usage Error: Couldn't find a script named "tsc".
```

Is there  a way to solve this?

**Background**

I know I can list the dependency specifically, but I cannot list it without version as far as I know. Listing version in every component breaks dependabot because of issues like https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/2178 so this is not an option for me.

Also, I know I can turn off PnP or switch to another package manager like pnpm. This is not this question, my question is if it is possible to solve while using yarn pnp.